# Can i update my monorepo nx workspace without upgrading angular version?

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Want to move from nx 10 workspace to 12 without moving away from angular 10.
`nx migrate latest` however upgrade also upgrade angular by default.

I searched https://nx.dev/previous/angular/core-concepts/updating-nx.
Nothing specific mentioned here.

Can someone please let me know if it is possible and if yes then could you provide the steps.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can update your nx monorepo without upgrading Angular with the next command:

```
nx migrate latest --to="@nrwl/angular@13.10.6"
```

Change `13.10.6` with the current version of that package. The side-effect is you can't use the Schematics this package provides.

Restore `typescript` package to the lastest version compatible with you Angular version

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
nx migrate @nrwl/workspace --to="angular/whatever@10.0.0,angular/other@10.0.0"
```